# Is "alignment" (or something else) a better word than "direction" for a senseless direction?

Tags: geometry, definition, affine-geometry

When I encountered the concept of direction being prior to the ordering of points on a line representing (parallel to) the direction, I thought it was a valuable distinction.  I resolved to keep this distinction in my work.  But that didn't last very long.

While taking notes on Schouten's Tensor Analysis book, I found myself writing things like: *there is a sense in which a line segment determines a direction without a sense.  A sense is determined by a ray.  So in order to talk about a line having a direction in the naive sense, we have to assign a sense to a senseless line.* ... ad nauseam.

It gets even worse when we talk about directed flat p-manifolds in $E_n.$

While pondering this predicament, I came upon the ideal of saying that a line determines an *alignment*, which when a relative ordering of points on the line is additionally specified, determines a *direction*.

Is the term *alignment* or some other, similar term ever used to denote the idea of direction without sense?

Is the term *alignment* used in mathematics in a way that would conflict significant with my proposed usage?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe oriented is the word you are looking for?

Comment: Or *unoriented*, rather: a line segment determines an unoriented direction.

Comment: No.  The connotation of orientation I'm familiar with indicates a sense of rotation.  It's what Schouten calls "screw-sense", which probably won't fly in today's culture.  If I don't find a prohibitive conflict with *aligned* I think I will stick with it.  Its common connotation isn't exactly what I intend, but *orientation* means *determining the easterly direction*.

Comment: @Steven: You're thinking of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(geometry), but we're talking about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space), in particular [orientation on a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)#On_a_line). But you're well within your rights to call it *alignment* if you like, as long as you define your terms in advance.

Comment: On the contrary.  My use of *orientation* is that which changes upon a permutation of axes.  See the discussions on pages 5 and 7: https://books.google.com/books?id=WROiC9st58gC I have to admit, I haven't sorted it all out, yet.  But I understand basically what he mans by *direction*, *direction with sense*, *p-direction* and *orientation*.

Comment: @Steven: On page 3 Schouten says that 1-dimensional orientation is called *sense*.

Comment: @Rahul I guess, if p-direction and p-orientation can be shown to be the same thing, then your vocabulary will work.  As I say, I haven't sorted out all of Schouten's  first chapter.

Answer (score -1):

I'd get in the word "colinear"/"colinearity".

--- rk

Comment: I'm trying to clarify, not obfuscate. ;) I do like the term "displacement" to connote the geodesic separation between two points (AKA a directed line segment.) That is, as an instance of the equivalence class of a vector.  I can probably justify that on the basis of Weyl's discussion in Space-Time-Matter, where he uses such a displacement as the prototype of a vector.  Einstein uses *interval* for that, but *interval* has come to mean a 4-displacement in SR.